# AWK to print after string match in file

Tags: macos, awk

i have written an awk command:

```
awk -F: '$1=="tag" {print $1;}' setup.py
```

I want to print everything after tag in quotes.

Sample input:

```
import tools

tools.setup(
    name='test',
    tag="0.0.8",
    packages=tools.ges(),
    line xyz
)
```

Output:
`0.0.8`

I was trying to output everything after tag but I can't even get that to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Using `match` function of `awk` to match regex `tag="[^"]*` which will match everything from tag=' to just before next occurrence of '. While printing it printing sub-string of matched part only and removing not needed part to get version part only.

```
awk 'match($0,/tag="[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` please try following. Using `oP` option in GNU `grep` where `P` option is responsible for enabling PCRE regex. In main program matching tag=" then using `\K` option to forget that matched value and matching just before next occurrence of `"` which will print the matched value then.

```
grep -oP 'tag="\K[^"]*' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `sed` please try following solution. Using `-E` option of `sed` which will enable ERE(extended regular expression) in program. Using `-n` option to stop printing of lines until we explicitly mention to print. In main program substituting matched value which is everything till tag and creating 1st and only backreference here which has everything between `"..."` between 2 double quotes and while performing substitution substituting it with only backed reference value and using `p` option printing matched value.

```
sed -E -n 's/.*tag="([^"]*).*/\1/p' Input_file
```

Comment: How do you print with the 3rd solution?

Comment: @qwerty, sure it's first I am stopping printing with -n then when a match is found printing that specific match only by -p option in sed

Comment: It doesn't print anything for me which is why I was asking. Actually the first method doesn't print either

Comment: @qwerty, it requires GNU sed may be it's the issue, you could use other 2 solutions then. All answers are tested and working fine for me. So only grep is working for you?

Comment: Grep doesn't work. It shows me usage for Grep when I run that. Please note there are spaces before the tag= (if that could be the issue).

Comment: @qwerty, all solutions work fine for me. What is the o.s you are using?

Comment: I am using MacOS

Comment: @qwerty, I don't have mac OS with me, but I believe `sed -r -n "s/.*tag='([^']*).*/\1/p" Input_file` could work for you. Please try this once and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: do you think the double quotes can cause an issue? Please note the quotes around tag weren't single, I had to change that.

Comment: @qwerty, no that shouldn't be an issue, If possible try installing with `brew` option `GNU grep` then 2nd solution will work. Also try my previous comment's sed solution which may work for mac OS. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @qwerty, yes they are double quotes in `sed` intentionally given there. Just adding this further to my previous comment.

Comment: Nope still nothing. I am trying to play around with it

Comment: @qwerty, my awk solution should work actually, that is irrespective of version, can you check it once, what error its giving?

Comment: It doesn't give any error. It simply doesn't print anything, runs fine

Comment: @qwerty, ohhhh you have changed input from `'0.0....'` TO `"0.0...."` let me change solutions now.

Comment: @qwerty, Try this once: `awk 'match($0,/tag="[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}' file` this should work

Comment: Okay, that worked and what @HatLess said worked but with with " and , at the end. Also the last comment should have RSTART + 9, RLENGTH - 9

Answer (score 1):

Using [gnu awk](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gawk), you could also match *tag=* with leading optional spaces from the start of the string and capture the tag version in a capture group.

`ary[1]` in the example code contains the group 1 value.

The pattern `^[[:blank:]]*tag="([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)"` matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[[:blank:]]*` Match optional spaces or tabs
- `tag="` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*` Match 1+digits and optionally repeat a `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `"` Match the closing `"`

gawk example:

```
awk 'match($0, /^[[:blank:]]*tag="([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)"/, ary) {print ary[1]}' setup.py
```

Output

```
0.0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple solution with `awk` could be:

```
awk -F'"' '/[[:digit:]]/{print $2}' file
0.0.8
```